# create control in run time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had task in web solution as button when I click on the button it create data list with some controls on data list and when I click second it create second data list and so on I want to know how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need placeholders like asp:panel, or even another datalist to add your datalists too. But, the basic idea is that, on the button click event, you instantiate a new datalist with controls, and add that datalist to the placeholder.

If there is a well-defined # of datalists, then you could put them in updatepanels and make them visible or invisible after the buttonclick.